Node.js and Tedious accessing SQL Server gives "Failed to parse URL" error
I'm  writing a simple API to query a SQL Server database.
I have this code in items.js:
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;  
var config = {  
    server: 'MyServer',  //update me
    synchronize: true,
    options: {
        trustServerCertificate: true,
        instanceName: 'MyInstance',
        database: 'MyDatabase',
    },
    authentication: {
        type: 'default',
        options: {
            userName: 'MyUserName', //update me
            password: 'MyPassword' 
        }
    },
};  
var connection = new Connection(config);  
connection.on("connect", function (err) {
    if(err) {
      console.log('Error: ', err)
    } else {
      console.log("Successful connection");
      executeStatement();
    }
  });

connection.connect();

var Request = require('tedious').Request;  
var TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES; 


function executeStatement() {  
    var request = new Request("SELECT 'SUCCESS' AS status, count(*) as itemCount FROM Inventory;", function(err) {  
    if (err) {  
        console.log(err);}  
    });  
    var result = "";  
    request.on('row', function(columns) {  
        columns.forEach(function(column) {  
          if (column.value === null) {  
            console.log('NULL');  
          } else {  
            //console.log(column);
            result+= column.metadata.colName + ": " + column.value + ", ";  
          }  
        });  
        console.log(result);  
        result ="";  
    });  

    request.on('done', function(rowCount, more) {  
    console.log(rowCount + ' rows returned');  
    });  
    
    // Close the connection after the final event emitted by the request, after the callback passes
    request.on("requestCompleted", function (rowCount, more) {
        connection.close();
    });
    connection.execSql(request);  
}  

If I run this by running "node items.js" I get the expected value returned.
Now if I want to call that code from my server.js file I change it like this:
module.exports = {
    getItemCount() {
      result = '';
      var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;  
      var config = {  
          server: 'MyServer',  //update me
          synchronize: true,
          options: {
              trustServerCertificate: true,
              instanceName: 'MyInstance',
              database: 'MyDatabase',
          },
          authentication: {
              type: 'default',
              options: {
                  userName: 'MyUserName', //update me
                  password: 'MyPassword' 
              }
          },
      };  
      var connection = new Connection(config);  
      connection.on("connect", function (err) {
          if(err) {
            console.log('Error: ', err)
          } else {
            console.log("Successful connection");
            result = executeStatement();
          }
        });
      
      connection.connect();
      
      var Request = require('tedious').Request;  
      var TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES; 
      return result;
    }
}
 
function executeStatement() {  
    var request = new Request("SELECT 'SUCCESS' AS status, count(*) as itemCount FROM Inventory;", function(err) {  
    if (err) {  
        console.log(err);}  
    });  
    var result = "";  
    request.on('row', function(columns) {  
        columns.forEach(function(column) {  
          if (column.value === null) {  
            console.log('NULL');  
          } else {  
            //console.log(column);
            result+= column.metadata.colName + ": " + column.value + ", ";  
          }  
        });  
        console.log(result);  
        // result ="";  
    });  

    request.on('done', function(rowCount, more) {  
    console.log(rowCount + ' rows returned');  
    });  
    
    // Close the connection after the final event emitted by the request, after the callback passes
    request.on("requestCompleted", function (rowCount, more) {
        connection.close();
    });
    connection.execSql(request);  
    return result;
}

Then I do this in my server.js:
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const items = require('./items');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000; // Use the port provided by the host or default to 3000
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello, Express!');
  });

// Read (GET) count of all items
app.get('/getItemCount', (req, res) => {
    // result = [{status: 'SUCCESS',itemCount: data.length}]
    result = items.getItemCount();
    res.json(result);
  });

And then I run server.js and go to http://localhost:3000/getItemCount, I get this error:

TypeError: Failed to parse URL from SELECT 'SUCCESS' AS status, count(*) as itemCount FROM Inventory;

Can anyone guide me as to how I can get this to work, please?

Neither You are correctly exporting nor importing  getItemCount() and executeStatement() from item.js.

Subha, I don't understand your comment

Well, Request is a class in the Javascript Fetch API and it's expecting a URL as input. If you want to use the Tedious version then at some point, probably inside your executeStatement function, you'll want to include var Request = require('tedious').Request.
